# why was this migrated

Tags: discussion

Why was this post migrated?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13627263/how-do-i-select-a-column-which-is-a-concatenation-of-two-columns-in-the-same-tab

It is similar to questions I would ask - I want to make sure I ask in the appropriate place.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was migrated because it was very basic SQL - the answer is essentially just to use string concatenation in a `WHERE` clause.

[From our FAQ](https://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) (emphasis added):

> ... but, dba.se is *not* the right place to ask questions about...
>   - Client-side programming - ask on Stack Overflow
>   - **Basic SQL - ask on Stack Overflow**
>   - Career advice, including salary or résumé - try Patrick McKenzie's Don't call yourself a programmer

What constitutes "Basic SQL" is a fuzzy line.  It's not an issue to ask it here (there's no penalty for having a post get moved) if you are in doubt.  It's very easy for mods (or higher-rep users) to move questions between sites if needed, so don't be afraid to ask something because you think it may be too basic.  If it is we can always move it.

---

Edit: jcolebrand

Keep in mind that the goal of this site (Database Administrators.Stack Exchange) is to answer questions for people facing the pains of managing databases. Asking front-end development questions that are primarily simple SQL, is the domain of Stack Exchange. "What constitutes a hard or an easy programming question?" you might ask. We're glad you do. When you figure it out, let us know. That's actively one of the hard questions of most sciences. :D